# Views Block Language Detection

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have a site with two languages (EN/FR). I have a Content Type (Article). I have a Block built with Views that is displayed on the Article Node page. This Views Block has a translation.

When the user switches to FR, all other Blocks and UI components detect and render in this language. Even if the user visits a node that does not have a FR translation, it will render the rest of the site in FR.

However, Views Blocks do not seem to adhere to the selected language. I must be missing something?

When a user changes the language of the site to FR, all translated interfaces should adhere to that, no?

Comment: Views blocks consist of two translatable parts - the configuration (the view) and the content. You have to translate the configuration through the interface, have you don this? Or is the content of the block the wrong language? If so, you'll have to add a filter for the content language.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know - I added translations in the Tab in the view-edit page that reads "Translate View". Regarding adding a filter: I would like the Views Block to display the user's selected language instead of the node's language. For example, if the node is only in EN, and the user is set to FR, I still want the FR version of the Views Block to show. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to set the filter on the content language then, and set it to use the current interface language.

Comment: Any chance you have a few minutes to walk me through this? I can pay you for your time.

Comment: You should remove your address. You'll get spammed! I'll try to post an answer below later

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view, add a new filter on 'translation language', and then for the filter, check the 'Interface text language selected for page' box, and save the view. This will filter the content of the view to the current language.